# Is it possible to specify that a table cell be required as long as there is a filled cell in the same row?

Tags: jquery, validation

http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/jDgnN/ shows my code. Currently, it simply makes all the cells `required`, whereas I wish to allow empty rows.

I have tried conditioning the `required` method like this:

```
"required:'#item0 input:filled'" - for row 0
"required:'#item1 input:filled'" - for row 1
```

Apparently this is wrong, because it does not work at all.

So, my question is how can I do it declaratively in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that those dependency expressions allow for something complicated enough (i.e. you want an "or" statement I think).  So what you might want to do is create a [custom validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) method to take care of this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("allRowOrNone", function(value, element) { 
    var $elements = $(element).parents('tr').find('input:filled');
    if ($elements.length == 0 || $elements.length == 3){
        return true;
    } else {
        return ($(element).val() != '');
    }
}, "Please specify all parts of the row");
```

Then change your rules to just simply `allRowOrNone`.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jDgnN/4/

Comment: Why or? I do not want all of the cells in the row to be filled. Enough if there is at least one filled cell. The reasoning is that I want to allow all empty rows, but otherwise the cells must be filled with data. So, I figured `required:'#item0 input:filled'` is good since it is supposed to say something like "required if the count of filled input fields in the row #0 is greater than 0". But it does not work.

Comment: @mark - What I've given you is: Either none of the inputs may be filled in a row OR All of the inputs in the row must be filled.  Are you saying it would be OK for a Quantity to be entered but no Item or Unit Price?

Comment: What you gave is what I want. So, what you are saying is that `required:'#item0 input:filled'` means if at most one cell is filled, not all the cells?

Comment: @mark - No, I think your idea is perfectly workable, it just won't work as an html attribute (like in the class attribute as I think you'd prefer).  If you wanted to stick with your plan, you could add some javascript that adds rules for each input with http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules .

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a problem with your solution. The plugin thinks that filled cells are invalid, just because there are some empty cells. However, only the empty cells should be invalid. This is why I am trying to make `required` work.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148005/does-the-latest-version-of-the-jquery-validation-plugin-support-conditional-vali ?

Comment: Do you know how can I make the validator revalidate the empty cells in a row as soon as the last filled cell is emptied? The problem is that changing a cell in this case changes the validity status of other cells, while that of the changed cell remains valid before and after the change. The plugin by default does not think there is anything to do and it is generally correct, but not in this particular case.